# xamarin Interstitia ad needs to click button twice to show up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, interstitial

I want to show an interstitial ad on button click.
The issue is that it needs to press the button twice in order to show up.

Interface

```
public interface IAdInterstitial
{
    void ShowAd();
}
```

Android class

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AdMobInterstitial))]
namespace CoronavirusTest.Droid
{
    class AdMobInterstitial:IAdInterstitial
    {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
        public AdMobInterstitial()
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);
            interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2981452032483899/1747111924";
            LoadAd();
        }
        void LoadAd()
        {
            var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
        }
        public void ShowAd()
        {
            if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded)
                interstitialAd.Show();
            LoadAd();
        }
    }
}
```

Button event

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IAdInterstitial adInterstitial = DependencyService.Get<IAdInterstitial>();
    adInterstitial.ShowAd();
}
```

Also added in manifest some code I found online which I read is needed in the application section

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code load ad at first button click and then IsLoaded property return true to show the ad at second button click.

You could try the code below.

```
  public interface IAdInterstitial
  {
    void LoadAd();
    void ShowAd();
  }
```

Android implement:

```
  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(AdMobInterstitial))]
  namespace XamarinDemo.Droid.DependencyService
  {
    public class AdMobInterstitial : IAdInterstitial
    {
      InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

      public AdMobInterstitial()
      {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);
        interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; //PUT YOUR ID HERE
        LoadAd();
      }

      public void LoadAd()
      {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
      }

      public void ShowAd()
      {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded)
            interstitialAd.Show();          
      }
   }  
}
```

Usage:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DependencyService.Get<IAdInterstitial>().LoadAd();
    }
    private void btnLoad_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DependencyService.Get<IAdInterstitial>().ShowAd();
    }     
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to navigate to home screen after ad I just use the Navigation.PushAsync(myPage) in button click?